# analytics.js loaded but no sign of visitors in my Google analytics Profile

Tags: joomla, gtmetrix

I own a website running by Joomla, I have a problem in using google analytics on my website. I put analytics code snippet, on all pages of my website and according to Gtmetrix result, analytic.Js loaded when I visit my website [PRJMArket.com](http://www.prjmarket.com)

Here are the [Gtmetrix results](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.prjmarket.com/1Ufy1FTt).

Please someone help me what is going on and why I can not perceive visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Analytics Free

That is the best plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin for joomla:

[Deconf Google Analytics for Joomla](https://deconf.com/advanced-google-analytics-joomla/)

Install the plugin, then enter your ID in the configuration. Make sure to "check-in" the plugin! To do so, select the plugin in the plugin list and click "check-in".